# How to access a model retrieved from one controller action in a different controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like a model retrieved by one controller action available in my other controller action but i'm not so sure sure on how i would go about this and hopefully someone on here can help me out..

I have got two methods like this:

```
//Method 1


        public ActionResult VehicleModel(int id)
        {

          //I would like to have access to this *model*   in my method2
         var  model = myService.VehicleModel(id);
            myService.Close();

            return Json(new { model = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

/

```
//Method2
  public ActionResult Vehicle(string id, string vehicle)
        {
            //this is the method where i need the *model* from method1 to be accessed 
            var _cat = _catalogue.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.vehicleId == id && x.Vehicle == vehicle );
            ViewData["id"] = id;
            return PartialView("_intercoolerVehicle", _cat);
        }
```

So basically in the above context .. I want method2 to have access to the model in method1. is it possible to do this? and if so, i would i go about in doing this?

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible as the variavble only __exists__ while it is in __scope__, i.e. only while the method 1 is running. Move it to class level!

Comment: No, you can't. A controller is instantiated per request. Call `var  model = myService.VehicleModel(id)` again in method 2.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that you are asking about controller actions and models. This is a fairly straightforward thing in MVC and I'm sure you'll get a good answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved your problem for now but strictly speaking you are approaching your controller actions wrongly. You should simply call your business domain service from any action wherever you want. If your intention is to have a centralized common function which should be doing the task of calling your business domain service to get the model data then better have a private function which is NOT exposed as a controller action. Then you can simply call that private function from any of your controller actions where you want. Hope this helps! You will need to replace the tag  with the type of the object returned by your business domain service as it is not evident from the code snippet you have posted in your question.

```
<Type returned by myService.VehicleModel function> globalModel = null;

        public ActionResult VehicleModel(int id)
        {
            globalModel = myService.VehicleModel(id);
            myService.Close();
            return Json(new { model = 3 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult Vehicle(string id, string vehicle)
        {
            //this is the method where i need the *model* from method1 to be accessed 
            VehicleModel(id);
            _catalogue = globalModel;
            var _cat = _catalogue.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.vehicleId == id && x.Vehicle == vehicle );
            ViewData["id"] = id;
            return PartialView("_intercoolerVehicle", _cat);
        }
```